# iMacros code to like Friends Facebook statuses

Tags: macros, firefox-addon, bots, imacros

I have written this code  in [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), a Firefox AddOn

It is designed to like all of my friends Facebook Statuses. I have a .csv file which contains a link to each of their Facebook profiles.

The code runs but it does not like my friends statuses.

Can anyone see what might be wrong with it?

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 30
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\TanPham\Documents\iMacros\List<sp>Friend<sp>Facebook.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=Title:Like<SP>this
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=Title:Like<SP>this
WAIT SECONDS=4
```

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to do. Make it clear what you want to achieve. Are you getting errors?

Comment: i want like all status my friend, in file csv is all link facebook friend....i wrote that code and that code run but code like status, don't like...i don't know that error, help me

Comment: So this code is designed to like all the statuses of your Facebook friends but for some reason it is NOT doing that?

Comment: that right, you can run this code and fix, thank so much

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect your intended requirements. Please ensure it is accurate.

Comment: @Deepend: thanks, that makes the question understandable.

Comment: Man if I had Facebook(FB) I would help you out man, I would test this. But I don't know the first thing about FB. Can you make like a recording of your screen of what exactly you want done?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you Using TAG POS={{!LOOP}}?

Do your 'Like' Buttton's positions change after each page refresh? If yes, you might use recording mode to export HTML elements.